# Simplifying a probability expression

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

If  and  are 2 random variables such that  ~ (0,1) and  ~ (0,1), and  = min(,), prove that:

$1 - \mathbb{P}(X > \sqrt{z}) \mathbb{P}(Y > \sqrt{z}) - 1 + \mathbb{P}(X > -\sqrt{z}) \mathbb{P}(Y > - \sqrt{z})$ = $\mathbb{P}(X \leq \sqrt{z}) - \mathbb{P} (X \leq -\sqrt{z}) - \mathbb{P}(X \leq \sqrt{z}) \mathbb{P} (Y > \sqrt{z}) + \mathbb{P}(X \leq -\sqrt{z})\mathbb{P}(Y \leq \sqrt{z})$.

I'm having trouble proving the above expression. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if there's a difference between $z$ and $Z$ but if no, then the first thing that comes to mind is that the normal distribution has the property $$\mathbb{P}(X<-a)=\mathbb{P}(X>a)$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I've tried using that, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere :(

Comment: If you substitute $$\mathbb{P}(X>\sqrt{z})=x$$ and $$\mathbb{P}(Y>\sqrt{z})=y$$ in the above what do you get? Note that everything can be expressed using $x$ and $y$ now

Comment: Got it, they both simplify to 1 - y - x. Thank you!